# JavaScript PUT file from text string

Tags: javascript, post, google-chrome-extension

How I can send file with PUT method if I have text string?
For example:

```
var new_data = 'hello world';
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("thefile", new_data);

var new_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
new_req.open("PUT", p.href, false);
new_req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
new_req.send(formData);
```

I getting empty response with HTML error 500 back. What I'm doing wrong? Uploader URL is right, I checked that.

Comment: you use chrome-extension or application local (file protocol)?

Comment: dont understand question correctly, but i execute that code in content script of chrome extension

Comment: your ajax is an extension for google chorme or are you using the ["FILE" protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)?

Comment: wow, sorry, im too noob in scripts and web techn. for answer. How can I find answer? I just use XMLHttpRequest class in content script. P.S. I didn't use links with "file:///" like write in Wiki.

Comment: Your AJAX is on a local server or WebServer? Why if your are not using ajax protolo file, not in a local server (`http://localhost`) is not in a webserver and not within an extension for GoogleChrome, then your Ajax file does not exist (LOL)

Comment: I'm really sorry I still understand nothing. I just write script and load in Chrome. I didn't configure something for ajax work.

Comment: You ajax is into Chrome-extension?

Comment: What "Url" is displayed in the address bar on the page that you are using ajax?

Comment: I use XMLHttpRequest from script from Chrome Extension. How can be adress bar in script? Url in code in my post (p.href) is like "https://uploader7o.disk.yandex.net:443/upload-target/20140918T021457.493.utd.5cmxksdxz6wz4xzlw7o1f0z85-k7o.939055""

Comment: That's what I asked in the first comment, "you use chrome-extension or application local (file protocol)?" Then it is determined that your ajax is a Chrome extension. So there is solution to your question, I will try to work out an answer, please wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add in your `manifest.json`:

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://*.disk.yandex.net/"
  ]
```

Read about: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Read this in [Yandex API](http://api.yandex.com/disk/api/reference/upload.xml)

> The only exception is for Chromium-based browser extensions: `Origin headers`
>   that begin with the schema `chrome-extension://` are simply ignored.

So the only thing missing was set permissions in your manifest.json.

---

> Note: PUT is only part of the instruction in "verb" of the HTTP
>   protocol, it alone nothing. This is what sets the SERVER-SIDE
>   language.

`PUT` and `POST` are similar. `POST` requires the times (depends on how you will send the file, eg. `RAW`):

```
.overrideMimeType("multipart/form-data");
.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

In others words, try this:

```
xmlhttp.open("PUT", p.href, false);
if (xmlhttp && xmlhttp.overrideMimeType) {
    xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("multipart/form-data");
}
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

Note: Prefer use Async, like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("PUT", p.href, true);//Async requires "true"
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log("OK", xmlhttp.responseText);
    } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        console.log("ERROR", xmlhttp.status);
    }
};
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

- Note: Async `xmlhttp.open("PUT", p.href, true);`
- Note: Sync `xmlhttp.open("PUT", p.href, false);`
- Error 500 can be a problem in htaccess (if apache) or other config in your server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried yours variant and it's still doesn't work :( I send this from Chrome Extension. In API desription of service written, that request must have not Origin header (but also written that for Chromium browsers Origin ignores). But since I had no else ideas i tried to null Origin by permissions. Unfortunately that not helps too. P.S. I always use async requests, thanks for advice, but now I just try to find way that will works. Then I will write async function.

Comment: `Origin` header don't affect, unless it is a failure on your server configuration. You are using apache or nigix? You are using PHP, Ruby, Python or other?

Comment: It's not my server, I use API methods to Yandex Driver http://api.yandex.ru/disk/api/reference/upload.xml but this document on russian, can not find eng version

Comment: I could not understand. Please send "HEADERS" (headers, multipart-data and entery response from Yandex) of the request in your QUESTION. Note: API in En: http://api.yandex.com/disk/api/reference/upload.xml

Comment: Ok, I read in Docs, "don't send `Origin`", wait a moment, please.

Comment: I did not get any method to remove "headers" I'll try again later.

Comment: I tried all variants with yandex, but still no... I tried even "http://*/" all http and https... Seems that there is no lodical solution. I send request to technical support of yandex.